# Copy/paste issue with my .vimrc file

Tags: macos, vim

When i try to copy in the visual mode and then paste it, its just pasting a new line instead of copied line. When the same thing done under root where it dosent use .vimrc it works fine.

This is the [.vimrc](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thesheff17/youtube/master/vim/vimrc) that i am currently using.
Any help is appreciated and one thing to note same .vimrc when used in linux it works fine.

Comment: What commands are you using to select copy and paste?

Comment: My wild guess is that this line here 
`set clipboard=unnamedplus`  could be causing these problems. Could you remove it and check it out?

Comment: @sudobangbang Yep that fixed it.

Comment: @kiran6: I think the answers provided by skeletalmonkey and me solves the issue for you. Could you accept one of the answers so that someone having the same problem will be benefited in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned it does work under Linux, I assume your error is on Windows or OSX. As mentioned by @sudobangbang your issue is with the line `set clipboard=unnamedplus`

What this does is set the default copy buffer for vim to be `+` which is vim's alias to the X Window clipboard used by Linux. Not sure why it's only giving you new lines but it's probably to do with how it interacts with the OS

To get this to work for Windows and OSX you'll want to use the command `set clipboard=unnamed` which sets the copy buffer to `*` which is the alias for the clipboard in Windows/OSX.

However if you remove that line entirely you can manually copy/paste from the system copy buffer by doing `"*y` and `"*p`using `"` to reference the `*` buffer followed by your command

Answer (score 1):

```
:help unnamedplus
```

provides me this information

> ```
>                                        clipboard-unnamedplus
> unnamedplus     A variant of the "unnamed" flag which uses the
>                 clipboard register '+' (quoteplus) instead of
>                 register '*' for all yank, delete, change and put
>                 operations which would normally go to the unnamed
>                 register.  When "unnamed" is also included to the
>                 option, yank operations (but not delete, change or
>                 put) will additionally copy the text into register
>                 '*'.
>                 Only available with the +X11 feature.
>                 Availability can be checked with:
>                         if has('unnamedplus')
> ```

vim.wikia article on [Mac OS X clipboard sharing](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_clipboard_sharing) suggests to use

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

Also take a look at options like `autoselect` and `autoselectplus`

```
:help autoselect
```

> ```
>                                            clipboard-autoselect
>     autoselect      Works like the 'a' flag in 'guioptions': If present,
>                     then whenever Visual mode is started, or the Visual
>                     area extended, Vim tries to become the owner of the
>                     windowing system's global selection or put the
>                     selected text on the clipboard used by the selection
>                     register "*.  See guioptions_a and quotestar for
>                     details.  When the GUI is active, the 'a' flag in
>                     'guioptions' is used, when the GUI is not active, this
>                     "autoselect" flag is used.
>                     Also applies to the modeless selection.
>
>                                            clipboard-autoselectplus
>     autoselectplus  Like "autoselect" but using the + register instead of
>                     the * register.  Compare to the 'P' flag in
>                     'guioptions'.
> ```